# "error: stray \255 in program" on Raspberry Pi

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, codeblocks, allegro

I'm having a problem in my program that I do not quite understand. The code itself looks perfectly fine. Also, I find it strange that this code works in [Code::Blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code::Blocks) for Raspberry Pi, but not on Code::Blocks for the [CHIP computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHIP_(computer)). Here is the stack trace:

```
home/chip/Desktop/SuperLuigiBros/startScreen.cpp:41:4: error: stray \255 in program
```

Here is the code:

#### File *startScreen.cpp*

```
createBrickArea(-15,600, 40, 20, "brBrick");
```

#### File *brick.cpp*:

```
void createBrickArea(int x, int y, int numBricks, int numRows, string brickType) {
    int brShadowWidth = 32;
    int brShadowHeight = 32;

    for (int i = 0; i <= numRows; i++) {
        if (brickType == "brick") {
            if (i == 0) {
                createBrickRow(x, y + 1, numBricks, "topBrick");
            }

            if (i % 2 == 0 && i != 0) {
                createBrickRow(x, y + 8 * i, numBricks, brickType);
            }

            if (i % 2 != 0 && i != 0) {
                createBrickRow(x + 8, y + 8 * i, numBricks, brickType);
            }
        }

        if (brickType == "brBrick") {
            createBrickRow(x, y + brShadowHeight * i, numBricks, brickType);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Octal 255 = 173 decimal = 0xAD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a character in your source file that isn't in the basic source character set. The error message tells you the location and value of that character: it's in column 4 of line 41 of `startScreen.cpp`. I don't think you've pasted the correct line of `startScreen.cpp` so I can't point it out, but you should delete that character.

Comment: Ok, I've deleted the character, so now the line is:

Comment: createBrickArea(15, 600, 40, 20, "brBrick");

Comment: nevermind, it turns out i just had to retype the line

Comment: @tsanglao, It looks like you had a [soft hyphen](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00AD/index.htm), whose UTF-8 and Windows-1252 encoding is 255 in octal.